# How to embed Python within C++ and call each other with PyBind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, cross-language, pythoninterpreter

I want to embed a Python interpreter within my C++ application, and make them call each other.
I followed the sample in the official doc of pybind11, and now I can call a python sub-program and create a object of python's class in the main program of c++, But my python class need to derive from a c++ base class.

Although there is a official sample about deriving a c++ base class within python, but it is extending python with a c++ module(in form of *.so file), not embedding a python interpreter into a c++ application.

There will NOT a shared library(*.so) file in my projects, if I `import myCppModule` in python, where would it find the module? How should I offer the module in C++?

If I blindly make a *.so file as a module for python, may I encounter a linking conflict?
Because there will be two binary code copies of my base class, one copy resides in main executable, and the other reside in the shared library.

Sorry for my ugly English.

Comment: its unclear what you want to do or what the problem is. "There will NOT a shared library(*.so) file in my projects" why not ? Thats the way to call C++ code from within python, and thats what you want to do, no?

Comment: Have you read the section about embedded modules? https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#adding-embedded-modules

Comment: @unddoch Thanks!!! I found it as you hint.  I should use PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE macro instead of using PYBIND11_MODULE, then I can export a python module in my main executable instead of a *.so file.

Answer (score 0):

According to @unddoch 's directive, I found that if we use `PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE` macro instead of using `PYBIND11_MODULE`, we can directly export a module for python in our c++ main executable without exporting a shared library file.
Maybe this can help others so I write it down here.